# generating raw trx and sending it to the network shows “transaction underpriced” error

Tags: php, transactions, ethereum, signature

I'm trying to make an ethereum raw transaction by **php** and these libraries:

https://github.com/simplito/elliptic-php

https://github.com/kornrunner/php-keccak

https://github.com/web3p/rlp

this is my code:

```
use Elliptic\EC;
use kornrunner\Keccak;
use Web3p\RLP\RLP;

$privateKeyHex = '.....'; // wallet private key
$toWallet = '118086be6247fBDa3BC64B4A11F07F3894aA1fAF';

$ec = new EC('secp256k1');
$key = $ec->keyFromPrivate($privateKeyHex );
$publicKeyHex = $key->getPublic('hex');
// $publicKeyHex => 0445e2caf0f227247dfa10440765812492e4d4c9df7b4e74d0d5cd3279fa80f5ef987a70e061ca20c06f09690957c9ba365cf06541181d1291e14c847d0d826583

$nonce= 0;
$gasPrice = 1e9;
$gasLimit = 21000;
$to = hex2bin($toWallet);
$value = 1e14-($gasLimit*$gasPrice)-1;
$inputData = 0;
//*********** EIP_155 *********
$chain_id = 1;
$r = 0;
$s = 0;
//*****************************

$SignData = [$nonce,$gasPrice,$gasLimit,$to,$value,$inputData,$chain_id,$r,$s];
$SignRlpData = rlpEncode($SignData);
$signHash = Keccak::hash(hex2bin($SignRlpData), 256);

$signature = $ec->sign($signHash ,$key);
$r = $signature->r->toString('hex');
$s = $signature->s->toString('hex');
$v = $chain_id*2 + ($signature->recoveryParam +35);

$trxData = [$nonce,$gasPrice,$gasLimit,$to,$value,$inputData,$v,hex2bin($r),hex2bin($s)];
$trxRlpData = rlpEncode($trxData );
// trxRlpData => f86980843b9aca0082520894118086be6247fbda3bc64b4a11f07f3894aa1faf8647d99eefefff8026a08a53214c92ff615c82eede2e51ab9d4d22d6a393f3ab8acee63c23d04e8e2fa7a07661f758f8b968d7597449ce05027edf3f2891fef0d1278f7330e99545109a2b




function rlpEncode($a){
    $rlp = new RLP;
    $encodedBuffer = $rlp->encode($a);
    return $encodedBuffer->toString('hex');
}
```

now after I send value of `$trxRlpData` to the ethereum network by https://etherscan.io/pushTx, show me this error message:

```
Error! Unable to broadcast Tx : {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"transaction underpriced"}}
```

but where is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved this problem with increasing a little *$gasLimit*.

```
$gasLimit = 21001;
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is a pending transaction and you try to send a new one with same `nonce` you see this error.

If you needs to make a new transaction while the old one has not confirmed yet, you must get pending transactions count `getTransactionCount` of address and use as `nonce`